# Expression for the tangent points of a parabola with a point. Why does this work?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

A couple of years ago I stumbled upon a curious expression that determines the tangent points to a parabola.

Given a point $A(x_a,y_a)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and a generic parabola $(p)$  $y = ax^{2} + bx +c$, the horizontal components of the intersection of the parabola with the tangent lines through $A$ are,

$$ x = \frac{ax_a \pm \sqrt{a({ax_a}^{2} + bx_a + c - y_a)}}{a} $$

These are the solutions to the system,

$$\begin{cases} y = ax^{2} + bx + c \\ y=2ax^2 + (b-2x_aa)x + (y_a-bx_a) \end{cases}$$

My problem is I have no idea where that second parabola came from. I wrote this down years ago but never followed up with an explanation (I know, I know).

Why does this work?

Comment: Have you tried solving the problem yourself, from scratch, and seen if you can get the second equation to appear? Because I guarantee you that any explanation of where it comes from is going to do exactly that. Why not try to make your own?

Comment: If tangent through $A$ passes through the point $(x,y)$ on the parabola, then the slope of this tangent is equal to $(y-y_a)/(x-x_a)$ and to $2ax+b$ (which is $f'(x)$, where $f(x)$ is the equation of the parabola). So the second equation is just $(y-y_a)/(x-x_a)=2ax+b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let m be the slope of the tangent, then

$$\frac{y - y_a}{x - x_a} = m => y = mx - mx_a + y_a$$

$$=> ax^2 + (b - m)x + c + mx_a - y_a$$

As the tangent only touch the parabola at one point, the determinant should be zero :

$$(b - m)^2 = 4a(c + mx_a - y_a)$$
$$=> m^2 - (2b + 4ax_a)m + b^2 - 4ac + 4ay_a = 0$$
$$=>m = b + 2ax_a \pm 2\sqrt{a(ax_a^2 + bx_a + c - y_a)}$$

From the equation for x we have

$$x = \frac{m - b}{2a} = \frac{ax_a \pm\sqrt{a(ax_a^2 + bx_a + c - y_a)}}{a}$$